# LINQ query for XML with difficult struct

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Please help me parse this XML. I use LINQ for this. My XML:

```
<path>
    <time>1234</time>
    <price>40</price>
    <length>7680</length>
    <transportTakes>2</transportTakes>
    <actions>
        <walk>
            <length>50</length>
            <toStop>24</toStop>
            <comment>Information</comment>
        </walk>
        <pass>
            <length>2350</length>
            <stops>24,785,234,644,53,89</stops>
            <routes>67,46,275,365,24</routes>
            <comment>Information</comment>
        </pass>
     <actions>
<path>
```

Also I have Class:

```
public class Path
{
    public Int32 Time { get; set; }
    public Int32 Price { get; set; }
    public Int32 Length { get; set; }
    public Int32 TransportTakes { get; set; }
    public List<PathActions> ActionsList { get; set; }
}
```

And Class:

```
public class PathActions
{
    public Int32 LengthActions { get; set; }
    public Int32 ToStop { get; set; }
    public String Routes { get; set; }
    public Int32 FromStop { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

Now, my method look like this:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(response);
Data.Path path = (from res in xDoc.Elements("path")
                  select new Data.Path()
                  {
                      Time = (Int32)res.Element("time"),
                      Price = (Int32)res.Element("price"),
                      Length = (Int32)res.Element("length"),
                      TransportTakes = (Int32)res.Element("transpotTakes"),
                      ActionsList = (from nextRes in xDoc.Elements("path")
                                                         .Elements("actions")
                                                         .Elements("walk")
                                     select new PathActions()
                                     {
                                         XName = (String)nextRes.Name.LocalName,
                                         LengthActions = (Int32)nextRes.Element("length"),
                                         ToStop = (Int32)nextRes.Element("toStop"),
                                         Routes = (String)nextRes.Element("routes"),
                                         FromStop = (Int32)nextRes.Element("fromStop"),
                                         Comment = (String)nextRes.Element("comment")
                                     }).ToList()
                  }).Single();
```

I dont know how i can get "walk" and "pass" in one LINQ query. I can parse only "walk" or only "pass", but i want to create object like my class Path.

Comment: How should `PathActions` be populated for a `pass`?  For example, where does `stops` go?  What should `ToStop` and `FromStop` be?

Comment: Are you saying you want a Linq query that returns "Walk" and "Pass" objects to both return as "PathActions?"

Comment: FYI it's considered best practice to use `int` and `string` instead of `Int32` and `String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
xDoc.Elements("path")
    .Elements("actions")
    .Elements()
    .Where(e => e.Name == "walk" || e.Name == "pass")
```

instead.

Of course in your query `res` is already an element in `xDoc.Elements("path")` so you really should use that to make sure you only add the actions associated with the current path element.

```
ActionsList = (from nextRes in res.Elements("actions")
                                  .Elements()
                                  .Where(e => e.Name == "walk" || e.Name == "pass")
               select ...).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed typos and error.  I think this is what you really want.

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string response =
                    "<path>" +
                        "<time>1234</time>" +
                        "<price>40</price>" +
                        "<length>7680</length>" +
                        "<transportTakes>2</transportTakes>" +
                        "<actions>" +
                            "<walk>" +
                                "<length>50</length>" +
                                "<toStop>24</toStop>" +
                                "<comment>Information</comment>" +
                            "</walk>" +
                            "<pass>" +
                                "<length>2350</length>" +
                                "<stops>24,785,234,644,53,89</stops>" +
                                "<routes>67,46,275,365,24</routes>" +
                                "<comment>Information</comment>" +
                            "</pass>" +
                         "</actions>" +
                    "</path>";




            var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(response);


            Data.Path path = xDoc.Elements("path").Select(res =>  new Data.Path() {
                                  Time = (Int32?)res.Element("time"),
                                  Price = (Int32?)res.Element("price"),
                                  Length = (Int32?)res.Element("length"),
                                  TransportTakes = (Int32?)res.Element("transportTakes"),
                                  ActionsList = res.Elements("actions").Elements().Select(nextRes => new PathActions()
                                  {
                                      XName = (String)nextRes.Name.LocalName,
                                      LengthActions = (Int32?)nextRes.Element("length"),
                                      ToStop = (Int32?)nextRes.Element("toStop"),
                                      Routes = (String)nextRes.Element("routes"),
                                      FromStop = (Int32?)nextRes.Element("fromStop"),
                                      Comment = (String)nextRes.Element("comment")
                                  }).ToList(),
                              }).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
    public static class Data
    {
        public class Path
        {
            public Int32? Time { get; set; }
            public Int32? Price { get; set; }
            public Int32? Length { get; set; }
            public Int32? TransportTakes { get; set; }
            public List<PathActions> ActionsList { get; set; }
        }
    }
    public class PathActions
    {
        public string XName { get; set; }
        public Int32? LengthActions { get; set; }
        public Int32? ToStop { get; set; }
        public String Routes { get; set; }
        public Int32? FromStop { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
    }

}
​
```